# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have these classes as my domain models:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public Guid Id { get;  set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get;  set; }
    public string Subject { get;  set; }
    public string Body { get;  set; }
    public string TicketStatus { get;  set; }
    public User SenderUserId { get;  set; }
    public User ReciverrUserId { get;  set; }
    public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
        public Guid Id { set; get; }
        public DateTime SubmitDate { set; get; }

        public string Fullname { set; get; }
        public string Permission { set; get; }
        public string Role { set; get; }//admin/agent/merchant
        public string Password { set; get; }

        public string NationalCode { set; get; }
        public string Email { set; get; }
        public string Telephone { set; get; }
        public string Mobile { set; get; }
        public string Address { set; get; }

        public CountrySection Provience { set; get; }
        public CountrySection City { set; get; }
        //public Department Department { set; get; }

        public CountrySection Town { set; get; }

        public ICollection<Merchant> Stores { set; get; }
        public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { set; get; }
        public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { set; get; }
}
```

When I add migration I get this error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Ticket.SenderUserId' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

Comment: Did you try doing what the error says?

Comment: Try following the naming conventions expected by EF: `SenderUserId` -> `SenderUser`, `ReciverrUserId` -> `ReceiverUser`

Comment: @abdusco I changed the name as you said but same error

Comment: Do you have any configuration in `DbContext.OnModelConfiguring`?

Comment: @abdusco No I don't

Comment: Then you need to. As the error says, it cannot determine the relation itself, so you need to nudge it in the right direction.

Comment: Have you used both classes Ticket and User in the same context or do you have a separate IdentityContext for User class?

Comment: EF can't determine if  `User.Tickets` belongs to `Ticket.SenderUser` or `Ticket.ReceiverUser` (I adapted the property names. One would expect `xxxId` to be a `Guid` property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 user properties in a Ticket class, but only one Ticket collection in User, try to fix it by adding another one

```
public class Ticket
{
    public Guid Id { get;  set; }
  .....
 public int SenderUserId { get;  set; }

   [ForeignKey(nameof(SenderUserId ))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.SenderUserTickets))]
    public User SenderUser { get;  set; }
    
      public int ReciverrUserId { get;  set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ReciverrUserId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.ReciverrUserTickets))]
    public User ReciverrUser { get;  set; }
   

public class User
{
        public Guid Id { set; get; }
        .....
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Ticket.SenderUser ))]
        public ICollection<Ticket> SenderUserTickets { set; get; }
         [InverseProperty(nameof(Ticket.ReciverrUser ))]
        public ICollection<Ticket> ReciverrUserTickets { set; get; }
}
```

Sorry I am using attributes since I like to keep everything in one place. You can translate them to fluent apis.  I added a couple of Ids too, but it is optional, EF can create the shadows.

Comment: I've never been downvoted for advocating *foreign key associations*. It's even the preferred way of working with EF, makes lots of things a lot easier.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you. You know I really appreciate your opiniton. Just there are some gurus here who doesn't think so.

Comment: @GertArnold I updated my answer. I hope it is better now.

Comment: It's common practice  to do it this way. There are those people (gurus?) who take an EF class model for a domain model (as in DDD), while it's nothing but a data access layer, totally committed to that task only. Those who try to use it as a domain model forget such a thing as "single responsibility", immediately disqualifying themselves as DDD experts.

Comment: @IMHO it was not the best idea of EF team  to make shadows properties, especially Ids, and many-to-many classes. There are a lot of novice developers who because of this doesnt understand that it is impossible to save the whole class instance to db and only one column can be saved, usually a primary key. And in many cases shadows makes query much more complicated then it could be.

Comment: Oh, from that angle, yes, it can be debated if FKs should be shadow properties or not. But it's certainly not a reason to DV an answer *whenever* FK properties are used. Maybe when shadow properties arguable are the best alternative. Hard to tell without an example.

Comment: @GertArnold The most projects usually starts from data structrure and creating EF.  And it is very hard to foreseen  in the begining what properties and classed would be needed , and what classes just for relations. This is  why I prefer not to use shadows. It is much easier just to add an extra line with property in the beginning, then trying to change the whole data schema when a project is almost ready. It is one of the most complicated things especially if db in production already. It is much easier to delete properties that was not used  by the end of the  project